# How do final fields prevent other threads from seeing partially constructed objects?

Tags: java, concurrency

I was looking into creating an immutable datatype that has final fields (including an array that is constructed and filled prior to being assigned to the final member field), and noticed that it seems that the JVM is specified to guarantee that any other thread that gets a reference to this object will see the initialized fields and array values (assuming no pointers to `this` are published within the constructor, see [What is an "incompletely constructed object"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513597/what-is-an-incompletely-constructed-object) and [How do JVM's implicit memory barriers behave when chaining constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513841/how-do-jvms-implicit-memory-barriers-behave-when-chaining-constructors)).

I am curious how this is achieved without synchronizing every access to this object, or otherwise paying some significant performance penalty. According to my understanding, the JVM can achieve this by doing the following:

1. Issue a write-fence at the end of the constructor
2. Publish the reference to the new object only after the write-fence
3. Issue a read-fence any time you refer to a final field of an object

I can't think of a simpler or cheaper way of eliminating the risk of other threads seeing uninitialized final fields (or recursive references through final fields).

This seems like it could impose a severe performance penalty due to all of the read-fences in the other threads reading the object, but eliminating the read-fences introduces the possibility that the object reference is seen in another processor before it issues a read-fence or otherwise sees the updates to the memory locations corresponding to the newly initialized final fields.

Does anyone know how this works? And whether this introduces a significant performance penalty?

Comment: Clarification relating to a deleted answer: As for the performance concerns I have, I'm not concerned with algorithmic performance issues pertaining to immutable data structures in general, only with performance degradation resulting from membarrier instructions. It's true a thread could "know" that once it issued a read-fence when accessing such an object, it doesn't have to issue any additional read-fences for that same object, but it's not clear if or how this is done, or if there's some other way of achieving the "final fields initialized" guarantee that I can't think of.

Comment: understood, that's why i deleted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the "Memory Barriers" section in [this writeup](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html).

A **StoreStore** barrier is required after final fields are set and before the object reference is assigned to another variable. This is the key piece of info you're asking about.

According to the "Reordering" section there, a store of a final field can not be reordered with respect to a store of a reference to the object containing the final field.

Additionally, it states that in `v.afield = 1; x.finalField = v; ... ; sharedRef = x;`, neither of the first two can be reordered with respect to the third; which ensures that stores to the fields of an object that is stored as a final field are themselves guaranteed to be visible to other threads before a reference to the object containing the final field is stored.

Together, this means that all stores to final fields must be visible to all threads before a reference to the object containing the field is stored.

Comment: If you want to do some digging through source, by the way, there are some links and discussions re: OpenJDK's implementation scattered through this email: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-compiler-dev/2012-February/007312.html -- I post this not as a concise source of info, but as a starting point for looking at some implementations on various platforms.