# Does adding "final" makea class more thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a question about thread-safety. By adding `final` to the states variable, does it really make the class more thread safe? Since I am not doing anything with states but reading it I could as well forget about `final`?

```
class UnsafeStates {
  private String[] states = new String[] { "AK", "AL" /*...*/ };

  public String[] getStates() {
    return states;
  } 
}
```

Comment: It doesn't prevent anyone from doing `getStates()[0] = "i am evil"`.

Comment: It protects against `states = new...` not on the indexes however.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144915/final-fields-and-thread-safety

Comment: To answer the real question (see my link up here): Yes it does make it more thread safe. But no, as pointed out by all the answers below, it's not completely thread safe as the array itself can still be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Someone can still change the values with final. with states[1] = "something";

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't change the values of the array, it's not thread-safe because the array is not safely published. The final keyword is needed here to ensure that the initial value of the array is visible to other threads.

Answer (score 0):

So if i gave back another object with the same values
like

```
    class UnsafeStates {
    private String[] states = new String[] { "AK", "AL" /*...*/ };

    public String[] getStates() {
    String[] states2 = new String[] { "AK", "AL" /*...*/ };
    return states2;
    } 
    }
```

it would be thread safe, right?