# Does non-final variable cause race condition?

Tags: java

I would like to understand if using a non-final variable would cause a race condition. I have a spring boot application where we instantiate a finagle client like shown below. Can this cause a race condition. If so why?

```
public class Client{

private JavaService<Request,Response> client;

Client(Config config){ 
this.client = create(config);
}

public CompletableFuture<Request, Response> testClient() {
 return client.apply();
}

}
```

Comment: As long as you do not reassign it, it does not matter

Comment: @Antoniossss It can if it's accessed by other threads.

Comment: @shmosel Its preset on construction time.

Comment: That's fine. But why is it non-final? That implies you might be doing something which isn't fine.

Comment: @Antoniossss Doesn't matter. If it's not [safely published](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#_safe_publication), it can be seen in a partially-constructed state by another thread, because there's no automatic *happens-before* edge between construction and assignment.

Comment: But its different as it reffers to lazy creation of object (in multi thead execution). Here you dont have that scenario and it would have to be dealt with on the caller level, in which case final not volatile nor any other modifier will help on this level

Comment: My assumption here is that OP is creating shared `Client` and passes it along to a worker threads and not creating it on the fly upon first usage by any worker.  I am aware of double check locking and its consequences and in my opinion it does not apply here. @shmosel

Comment: I didn't say anything about DCL (it's only used as an example in my linked article). My point is, when you construct an object without final fields, it can be seen in an unconstructed state by another thread, depending on how it's shared. Given that OP didn't clarify if or how it's being shared, that should remain a concern.

Comment: I see your point and you are right https://stackoverflow.com/a/7145024/1527544